# Is there a reliable memory-retention guidance chart?

Tags: learning, memory

As discussed [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/how-are-these-review-forgetting-curve-calculated) reliability of some charts are dubious. I would like to use such a chart for studying purposes and am looking for something peer-reviewed or as factual as possible. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this graphic:

[image]

It is taken from an article from WIRED, [Want to Remember Everything You'll Ever Learn? Surrender to This Algorithm](https://www.wired.com/2008/04/ff-wozniak/). It talks about Piotr Wozniak and his spaced repetition software [SuperMemo](https://www.supermemo.com/en).